# Flutter: How to Retrieve field within documents below

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to retrieve the hasVoted field within all these documents shown in the image attached (i have that hasVoted field within all the documents created). Below is my code but it does not seem to be working. What am i doing wrong and what is the proper way of retrieving those fields?

```
_checkUserVotes(context, data) async {

bool hasVoted = false;
final record = Record.fromSnapshot(data);

getData() async {

return await Firestore.instance.collection("finance").getDocuments();

}

getData().then((val){

if(hasVoted == true){

  return Text("Sorry you have voted already");
}

else if(hasVoted != true){

 return GestureDetector(

    onTap: () => record.reference.updateData({'votes': record.votes + 1}),

  );
}
});
}
```

[this is the Backened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seRVj.png)

Comment: See, from the image, I can see, that there is an ID for the hasLiked, to see who has liked it. Use it to see whether the person has liked it or not. Match with the userID with the hasVoted Key, and then get the value.

Comment: @Alok, thanks for your response. There is no hasLiked in the image attached, instead there is hasVoted. Concerning this aspect of your comment, (Match with the userID with the hasVoted Key, and then get the value.) Can you please explain further. Forgive mine asking, i am new to flutter and this is my very first App.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your collection is called *finance* you need to access the `Map` field that is inside *each* document.

```
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection("finance").getDocuments();

snapshot.documents.forEach((document){
      if(document.data != null && document.data['hasVoted']['yourId']){
        print('Has voted');
      }
    });
```

Now the thing is, I don't know where do you get that `yourID` property from, but you should now.

If you want to iterate from them all, just use the value(s) directly from that map.

```
snapshot.documents.forEach((document){
      if(document.data['hasVoted'] is Map && (document.data['hasVoted'] as Map).values.first){
        print('Has voted');
      }
    });
```

But I really recommend you to parse that data into a model (eg. `MyModel.fromData(document)`) that way you really increase the readability of your code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The ID property is the ID of the authenticated user. I manually pasted it there as i had no idea on how to programmatically send it there. It purpose is to check if the user has voted already or not. If yes, then the next vote won't count, if no, then the vote will count.

Comment: Your answer was perfect i did vote it but it seems i have low reputation so it didn't show. I think my question was suppose to be in two parts. Part 1 is what you answered and Part 2 is that, i need to have the votes seen in the Backend increase when a user votes. The user should be made to vote only once in each category. This is the part i should have added to the question. If you have any idea on that, you can help please. Thanks @asbovelw